# Apache Arrow - not all nodes and buffers were consumed error when writing a map field

Tags: java, apache-arrow

I have a java code that writes a map field to a file and then read from the file by using Apache Arrow. During the read, when loading the record batch I got the not all nodes and buffers were consumed error. Below is the code:

```
File file = new File("/temp/test.arrow");
Schema schema;

      try (BufferAllocator allocator = new RootAllocator()) {
         Field keyField = new Field("id", FieldType.notNullable(new ArrowType.Int(64, true)), null);
         Field valueField = new Field("value", FieldType.nullable(new ArrowType.Int(64, true)), null);
         Field structField =
               new Field("entry", FieldType.notNullable(ArrowType.Struct.INSTANCE), List.of(keyField, valueField));
         Field mapIntToIntField = new Field("mapFieldIntToInt", FieldType.notNullable(new ArrowType.Map(false)), List.of(structField));

         schema = new Schema(Arrays.asList(mapIntToIntField));
         try (
               VectorSchemaRoot vectorSchemaRoot = VectorSchemaRoot.create(schemaPerson, allocator);
               MapVector mapVector = (MapVector) vectorSchemaRoot.getVector("mapFieldIntToInt")) {
            UnionMapWriter mapWriter = mapVector.getWriter();
            mapWriter.setPosition(0);
            mapWriter.startMap();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
               mapWriter.startEntry();
               mapWriter.key().bigInt().writeBigInt(i);
               mapWriter.value().bigInt().writeBigInt(i * 7);
               mapWriter.endEntry();
            }
            mapWriter.endMap();
            mapWriter.setValueCount(1);
            vectorSchemaRoot.setRowCount(1);

            try (
                  FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                  ArrowFileWriter writer = new ArrowFileWriter(vectorSchemaRoot, null, fileOutputStream.getChannel())) {
               writer.start();
               writer.writeBatch();
               writer.end();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }

      // Deserialize Arrow data from a file
      try (
            BufferAllocator rootAllocator = new RootAllocator();
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            ArrowFileReader reader = new ArrowFileReader(fileInputStream.getChannel(), rootAllocator)) {
         for (ArrowBlock arrowBlock : reader.getRecordBlocks()) {
            reader.loadRecordBatch(arrowBlock);  // error thrown here
            VectorSchemaRoot vectorSchemaRootRecover = reader.getVectorSchemaRoot();

            System.out.print(vectorSchemaRootRecover.contentToTSVString());

            int totalCount = vectorSchemaRootRecover.getRowCount();
            Schema schema = vectorSchemaRootRecover.getSchema();

            for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
               for (Field field : schema.getFields()) {
                  String fieldName = field.getName();
                  Object arrowValue = vectorSchemaRootRecover.getVector(field).getObject(i);
                  System.out.println("fieldName: " + fieldName + ", arrowValue: " + arrowValue);
               }
            }
         }
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks!

By debugging the code, looks like write works as expected. I can see the correct data in `vectorSchemaRoot`, not sure if any setting is missing during the write that caused the error in loading the file.